# How to run SQLAlchemy on AWS Lambda in Python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mysql-python

I preapre very simple file for connecting to external MySQL database server, like below:

```
from sqlalchemy import *

def run(event, context):
    sql = create_engine('mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1/scraper?charset=utf8');
    metadata = MetaData(sql)

    print(sql.execute('SHOW TABLES').fetchall())
```

Doesn't work on AWS, but localy on Windows works perfectly.

Next, I install by `pip install sqlalchemy --target my/dir` and prepare ZIP file to upload packages to AWS Lambda.

Run, but with failed message `No module named 'MySQLdb': ModuleNotFoundError`.

Then, I use `pip install mysqlclient --target my/dir`, create ZIP and again upload to AWS Lambda.

Run, but with new failed message `cannot import name '_mysql': ImportError`.

So, what I should doing now?

Comment: It might be missing the MySQL client libraries. The python libraries afaik are wrappers around the C implementation.

Comment: It is possible to install?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> SQLAlchemy includes many Dialect implementations for various backends.
>   Dialects for the most common databases are included with SQLAlchemy; a
>   handful of others require an additional install of a separate dialect.
>
> The MySQL dialect uses mysql-python as the default DBAPI. There are
>   many MySQL DBAPIs available, including MySQL-connector-python and
>   OurSQL

Instead of `mysql` you may use `mysql+mysqlconnector`

```
sql = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:root@127.0.0.1/scraper?charset=utf8')
```

Then use:

```
pip install mysql-connector --target my/dir
```

Create Zip and again upload to AWS Lambda.

Comment: I normaly instatiate ‘db = SQLAlchemy()’ and then use db.session, any idea on how would that work in this case?

Comment: Should this be included as a `layer`? or the function code itself?