# Using Flask-SQLAlchemy with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, aws-lambda

I have a Flask app up and running on my localhost.
I normally instantiate the SQLAlchemy object to `db` with `db = SQLAlchemy()` and then use a few basic functionalities, like: `db.drop_all()`, `db.create_all()`, `db.session.add(MyClass)`, `db.session.commit()`.

Used Zappa to deploy my Flask web app to AWS Lambda, and even though I froze my pip requirements, I'm getting the following error:

`ImportError: cannot import name '_mysql' from 'MySQLdb'`

Now, I ran into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54592664/8930321), but it considers pure SQLAlchemy ORM, and new package (outside my venv, from what I understood).

I was wondering what would be the best way to solve my issue with my current setup (I normally don't create the engine, for example).

Any ideas/suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

After a lot of investigating, it seems that there's a bug in the `_mysql` module. Reading it's GitHub docs:

> Versions of MySQL Connector/C may have incorrect default configuration
>   options that cause compilation errors when mysqlclient-python is
>   installed. (As of November 2017, this is known to be true for
>   homebrew's mysql-connector-c and official package)
>
> Modification of mysql_config resolves these issues as follows.
>
> Change

```
# on macOS, on or about line 112:
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

> to

```
# Create options
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

But I just can't seem to find `mysql_config`. While typing `nano mysql_config` on the terminal (with my `venv` activated), I get an empty file. I would imagine that solving this configuration would solve the module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problems using MySQL with AWS Lambda in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763380/problems-using-mysql-with-aws-lambda-in-python)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but related - thanks for the links. Tried updating the SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI with `mysql+pymysql` without success also...

Comment: Have you tried the mysql_config fix for Mac here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/12708157/8751739